# `mongoose.connect()` fires error: first argument should be String, received

Tags: node.js, mongoose

> throw new MongooseError('The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be
> a ' +
> ^
>
> MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string,
> got "undefined". Make sur
> first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (C:\Users\niko\Desktop\opaa\node_modules\mongoose\nnection.js:694:11)
> at _mongoose._promiseOrCallback.cb (C:\Users\niko\Desktop\opaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\js:351:10)
> at promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\niko\Desktop\opaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promislback.js:10:12)
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (C:\Users\niko\Desktop\opaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\inde    at
> Mongoose.connect
> (C:\Users\niko\Desktop\opaa\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:350:20)
> at Object. (C:\Users\niko\Desktop\opaa\app.js:9:10)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
> at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
> at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:831:12)
> at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
> at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:622:3)

```
const { response } = require('express');
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const dotenv = require('dotenv')
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

dotenv.config();

mongoose.connect( process.env.DB_CONNECT,  { useNewUrlParser: true }, () =>{
    console.log("connected to db");
});

const route = require('./routers/routers');
const { connect } = require('./routers/routers');

const app = express();

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(express.json());

app.set("views", "views")
app.set("view engine", "hbs")

app.use(express.static('public'));

app.use('/user', route);

app.listen(3000, () => console.log("Server Is Runing on localhost:3000"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to be sure you've passed the `DB_CONNECT`.

you may try `DB_CONNECT=YOUR_DB_URI node index.js`

also, you may check with `console.log(process.env.DB_CONNECT)` at the beginning of your script.

Answer (score 0):

The error message tells that the `mongoose.connect` received URL is `undefined`. I suggest you instead `process.env.DB_CONNECT` try passing an URL to the DB for testing purpose see if that works.

The issue is with the `process.env.DB_CONNECT` is not setting up correctly, you might need to check `dotenv` configuration.